# About the definition of homotopic equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Are the definition for homotopy relation between a pair of path and the definition for homotopy relation for the topological spaces are different?
Thanks.

Comment: Your two questions are quite disconnected. The "If yes" makes no sense.

Comment: I want to rephrase the Question to, How a disc in $R^2$ space is homotopicaly equivalent to a point?

Comment: You can edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shrink the disc continuously along radii to the center. Homotopic equivalence doesn't mean the spaces are the same (homeomorphic). These two obviously aren't.

Here's the definition from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html):

> Two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if there exist
>   continuous maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$, such that the composition $f \circ  g$
>    is homotopic to the identity $\text{id}_Y$ on $Y$, and such that $g \circ f$
>   is homotopic to $\text{id}_X$. Each of the maps $f$ and $g$ is called a
>   homotopy equivalence, and $g$ is said to be a homotopy inverse to $f$ (and
>   vice versa).

This is an equivalence relation: it's clearly symmetric in $X$ and $Y$.

In your question, take $f$ to be the contraction along radii and $g$ to be the identity mapping the center to itself.

Wolfram continues

> Some spaces, such as any ball $B^k$, can be deformed continuously into a
>   point. A space with this property is said to be contractible, the
>   precise definition being that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a point. It
>   is a fact that a space $X$ is contractible, if and only if the identity
>   map $\text{id}_X$ is null-homotopic, i.e., homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: But then this is not an equivalence relation, because equivalence relations have symmetric property.

Comment: "Homotopically equivalent" is symmetric - see my edits.

Comment: It is symmetric if the identity map $id _X$ is null- homotopic.